# There exists a perfect square between $n$ and $2n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, square-numbers

I need help proving the following mathematical statement:

> Prove that for every $n$ there is a $k$ such that $n \leq k^2 \leq 2n$ where $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$.

Could someone get me started or give me some advice on proving this statement?

Comment: This must be a duplicate. You can do a search for an exact question. A hint: $\sqrt n+1< \sqrt{2n}$.

Comment: Advice: search before asking. Also, write titles that describe the specific question, so that others can find it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete the base case of $n=1$ first. Then suppose that the inequality holds for all $n \in \{1,2\ldots, p\}$. We at least know $p \leq k^2 \leq 2p$ for some $k$ and some $p$. If $k$ is such that $p+1 \leq k^2 \leq 2(p+1)$ you're done. So suppose the case that $p+1>k^2$. This means $p = k^2$, which leads to the inequality $$p+1<(k+1)^2 = k^2+2k+1 \leq 2k^2+1 < 2k^2+2 = 2p+2 = 2(p+1)$$

The inequality above only works if $k \geq 2$. Can you prove this must be true for $n>1$?

Comment: Would I be able to manipulate the inequality in the following way:

$$p+1 < k^2+2k+1 < 2p+2$$

So since, $$k^2 = p$$ Then,

$$p+1 < p+2sqroot(p)+1 < 2p+2$$

Now if I can prove this for: $$n>1$$ I am done?

Comment: I am confused I'm sorry... wouldn't rewriting the inequality in that way simply follow from the way you have written it? Then I would just prove the inequality holds for n > 1?

I mean I am not changing anything about it just rewriting it.

Comment: Can we not use transitivity to sort out the inequality in some way?
I mean just simply since:
 $$a>b>c$$ Then, $$a>c$$
Maybe there is some logical step I'm not understanding...

Comment: I see. But since that inequality was arrived at by, $$p=k^2$$, $$p=9, k=4$$ Would not work since, $$4^2$$ Does not equal: $$9$$ So within that particular inequality, $$k^2$$ Must be such that: $$k^2=p$$ Could this work?

Comment: @StefanT Ah maybe I misunderstood your very first comment. Are you saying that *after* the work I did to reach $p+1<k^2+2k+1<2p+2$ under the case that $p = k^2$, you wish to further manipulate the inequality in the way you outlined in your very first comment?

Comment: Yes sorry maybe I was confusing in my text, but that's what I'm saying. I would manipulate it to: $$p+1<p+2\sqrt{p}+1<2p+2$$ Now I would simply prove that this inequality holds for n >1? This is all after the work you have done to reach the original inequality.

Comment: There is no need to manipulate the inequality past what I did. What I did is the end of the proof. The induction hypothesis gives us some $k$ and some $p$ so that $p \leq k^2 \leq 2(p+1)$. If $p<k^2$ then $p+1 \leq k^2 <2(p+1)$ which takes care of that case. Otherwise if $p = k^2$ I completed the inequality to find a new integer $k' = k+1$ so that $p+1<(k')^2<2(p+1)$. In either case we have shown that if the proposition $P(p)$ is true then it implies $P(p+1)$ is true. That ends the induction proof

Comment: That makes perfect sense now. Thank you very much.